# Rundeck receiving Token is not authorized for webhook message

Tags: webhooks, rundeck

I have created a webhook to run one of my Rundeck Jobs. On performing a POST to the url provided I get the error message below.

Is there something that needs to be enabled or do I need to pass an authorization token in with the curl request to trigger the webhook? Or is there something in the acl that needs adding for Webhooks?

```sh
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST; Unknown error
<result error='true' apiversion='33'><error code='unauthorized'><message>(Token:gcGab****) is not authorized for: /api/33/webhook/gcGabctaO9lzypoEIUWYQTwI3OCj7g9z</message>
```

I expected just to be able to POST to the provided url and can't see anything in the docs regarding authorization.

Comment: Hi! How do you call the API? You can post command to call the job? You need to create a Token for your user to access API. For that go to user icon (up to right) > Profile > Click on "+" at "User API Tokens" and click on "Generate New Token" button. Now you can see the token if you click on "Show Tokens" button.

Here you have a good example to use Rundeck API: 

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest#intro

Comment: curl POST "http://localhost:4440/api/33/webhook/gcGabctaO9lzypoEIUWYQTwI3OCj7g9z" --header "Rundeck-Auth-Token: qDhQ4HjFWW9XYszZMnJDf94CNXMSAvs6"
I've tried various other headers and nothing I have tried has worked. I've also tried passing the auth token in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Token for your user to access API. For that go to user icon (up to right) > Profile > Click on "+" at "User API Tokens" and click on "Generate New Token" button.

And call the job with:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4440/api/32/job/42a78f86-094d-47dc-8914-896b5f7594f3/run?authtoken=UVRPI30FXS4X8zhToyPljbEUcsUBUCyG
```

Your webhook:

```
http://localhost:4440/api/32/job/42a78f86-094d-47dc-8914-896b5f7594f3/run?authtoken=UVRPI30FXS4X8zhToyPljbEUcsUBUCyG
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is giving the user running the webhook permission in the ACL (the documentation https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authorization.html#rundeck-resource-authorizations says you need "post" permission, but for me it didn't work until I added "admin").

```
    - equals:
        kind: webhook
      allow: [admin,read,create,update,delete,post]
```

The API token was not required.